# Looking for suitable methods to check goodness of a model based on the residuals or prediction errors?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, time-series, signal-processing, noise

I am looking for suitable methods to check goodness of my model based on the residuals or prediction errors. I want to make sure that the model residuals or prediction errors are normally distributed and uncorrelated. I would appreciate your suggestions.
Thanks,
Iman

Answer (score 0):

ACF(yourmodel$residuals) and ACF(yourmodel$residuals^2): if both correlograms suggest that the residuals of the fitted model behave like white noise, you can make sure you did right.